# Calculating Mass Inertia Matrix from URDF in Lua

Tags: lua, rospy

I want to calculate the Mass Inertia Matrix from URDF in Lua. I used [pykdl](http://wiki.ros.org/pykdl_utils) in ros, which has a function for calculating inertia matrix ([see here](https://github.com/gt-ros-pkg/hrl-kdl/blob/hydro/pykdl_utils/src/pykdl_utils/kdl_kinematics.py#L293) and [see here](https://github.com/rethink-kmaroney/baxter_pykdl/blob/master/scripts/baxter_kinematics.py#L68)). It uses KDL structure internally, which can be initialized from URDF file.

For some reason, I am using Lua and I need Mass Inertia Matrix. Can someone propose any workaround for the same?

Comment: I think that you will have to either write it yourself, or pass data to python script and get the output.

Comment: @DanilGaponov: Passing data to python and use it inside LUA might not be time efficient. Since I need these data in real time. Can you explain more?

Comment: Idea was to just call the python script from Lua. This won't be very efficient. So I think you will have to reimplement the required functions in Lua. Or maybe find a C library.

Comment: @DanilGaponov: Thanks again. Can you quickly summarize how it should be re-implemented in Lua ? I need to calculate only Mass Inertia Matrix from URDF file.

Comment: I don't actually have knowledge on the topic. You need to know the algorithm and implement it in Lua using python code as reference. You can also try to re-write the python code without understanding of underlying algorithm, but I think, that it will be more difficult.